# Prolog condition making

Tags: prolog

--Is the if else representation given below correct?

--I want if-else statements to interpret as:

if grade is NC and course is CDC then call isNCinCDC or

if grade is NC and course is seminar then call isNCinCDC or

if grade is NC and course is thesis then call isNCinCDC or

if grade is NC and course is electives then call isNCinELEC or

if grade is NC and course is Practice school then call isNinPS or

if grade is NC and course is Project Course then call isNinPC

```
isNCCalc([],[],[]) :-
display('There are no more courses to check for NC').

isNCCalc([G|T1],[S|T2],[C|T3]) :-
    (((G == 'NC' , C == 'CDC') -> isNCinCDC(S)) ;
    ((G == 'NC',C == 'SEMINAR'-> isNCinCDC(S)) ;
    ((G == 'NC',C == 'THESIS' -> isNCinCDC(S)) ;
    ((G == 'NC',C == 'ELECTIVES' -> isNCinELEC(S)) ;
    ((G == 'NC',C == 'PRACTICE SCHOOL' -> isNCinPS(S)) ;
    ((G == 'NC',C == 'PROJECT COURSE' -> isNCinPC(S)))),
    isNCCalc(T1,T2,T3).
```

Comment: You should use **facts** for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can write it more simply, because

```
3 ?- display((a,b->c)).
->(,(a,b),c)
true.

4 ?- display(((a,b)->c)).
->(,(a,b),c)
true.
```

i.e. conjunctions (the comma) bind more strictly than implication (the arrow). Then

```
isNCCalc([G|T1],[S|T2],[C|T3]) :-
    (   G == 'NC', C == 'CDC'
    ->  isNCinCDC(S)
    ;   G == 'NC', C == 'SEMINAR'
    ->  isNCinCDC(S)
    ;   G == 'NC', C == 'THESIS'
    ->  isNCinCDC(S)
    ;   G == 'NC', C == 'ELECTIVES'
    ->  isNCinELEC(S)
    ;   G == 'NC', C == 'PRACTICE SCHOOL'
    ->  isNCinPS(S)
    ;   G == 'NC', C == 'PROJECT COURSE'
    ->  isNCinPC(S)
    ;   true
    ),
    isNCCalc(T1,T2,T3).
```

I added true as last alternative, since either you could move G=='NC' in the head, and simplify more, or the loop will fail altogether when a G\='NC' appears. Not sure about, you didn't specified what you want in that case.